# Send sms without user Interaction iPhone

Tags: iphone, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have seen an application which name is "Glympse". In this application sms is sending without user interaction which is not possible for iPhone. I have show in my device log that "Glympse" application call mfmessagecontroller.

```
Jul 10 16:24:13 unknown Glympse[3004] <Warning>: GlympseAppDelegate::sendViaSMSWithMessage:toRecipient:withDelegate:
Jul 10 16:24:13 unknown Glympse[3004] <Warning>: 0
Jul 10 16:24:13 unknown Glympse[3004] <Warning>: presentModalViewController
Jul 10 16:24:14 unknown Glympse[3004] <Warning>: messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:
Jul 10 16:24:14 unknown CommCenter[57] <Notice>: queuing sms message with id 584
Jul 10 16:24:14 unknown SpringBoard[52] <Error>: mms: queued messageId 584
```

In my application I also need that so how i implement that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before asking questions, please use the [search feature](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sms+without+user+iphone) as this has been asked MANY times before.

Comment: @NickBull i have checked all question but i don't get any solution. And i show this in app that's y i asked a question. And thanks for guidance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With **`MFMessageComposerViewController`** it is not possible to send without user interaction.

You have to take SMS gateway and implement your own way of sending SMS, than only it is possible. Like you have to create webservice and accept parameters from iPhone like phonenumber and message and than send SMS using SMS gateway.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With current SDK it is not possible to do so. If you feel they have done so they may have created interface like that i.e. designed their own message composer and handled accordingly. But with MFMessageComposerViewController it is not possible at all.

Comment: Janak Nirmal, you are not quite correct on that. In iOS 4 and 5 it was possible to present the controller, find "Send" button and programmatically press it. Few applications were leveraging this hidden feature. Apple never banned anyone for doing so. In iOS 6 they changed the underlying design of MFMessageComposerViewController (it is now based on a concept of "remote view"), which prevents the hack described above from working. But in old days..

Answer (score 2):

Glympse does not send SMS, it launches a web request to its server. The server has an SMS engine, it sends the SMS accordingly to the parameters from the request. Otherwise it's impossible to achieve this feature.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: The answer below is only relevant for iOS 5.1 and earlier.  It looks like Apple has prevented the behavior from working in iOS 6, and in fact Glympse has reverted to their earlier strategy of sending the text with user interaction.

Playing with Glympse confirms the behavior ios describes in the question.  Although Glympse does use its own server to generate SMS message when it can't send a text directly from the device, it will send the text directly from the device (using iMessage or SMS) when the capability is there.  You can verify this by sending a request and then seeing that the resulting text message shows up in your message history.

Even though **`MFMessageComposeViewController`** looks intended to require user interaction, the log messages left behind by Glympse very strongly suggest they are using it and suppressing the UI.  I experimented and found that it's not too difficult to do something that behaves the same way: I simply replaced the view of the MFMessageComposeViewController (to avoid displaying the UI), and then after calling **`presentViewController`** I set a timer event to fire after the controller was up and running.  The timer event sent a **`send:`** message to the controller which simulates the user clicking on the "Send" button.

What I can't answer is whether this follows the terms of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement -- it could potentially conflict with the "use documented APIs in manner prescribed by Apple" (3.3.1) or the general "don't interfere with warnings Apple tries to provide to users" (3.3.14).  Glympse is taking advantage of this behavior for the good of the user -- it very clearly improves the user experience and avoids sending messages without the user's knowledge/consent.  I'd like to take advantage of the behavior too.  But you can also see that this behavior could be used by shady apps to impersonate users, send spam, etc.  If this becomes common practice, Apple might well start looking for this behavior and rejecting apps that use it (maybe even Glympse will have to pull the behavior out).

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the way to do this exists here: [`https://github.com/0xced/Stealth-Messenger`](https://github.com/0xced/Stealth-Messenger)

But you could the developer clearly saying:

> Do not use! This stuff is for education purpose only and is not
>   suitable for the App Store at all.

at the bottom. But only for "education purposes" you can check this out.